# err: TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I'm trying to send form via a POST request this way:

client side

```
angular.module('app').controller('contactCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.envoyer = function(nom, organisation, courriel, telephone, message){
        $http.post('/contact', {nom:nom, organisation:organisation, courriel:courriel, telephone:telephone, message:message}).then(function(error, response){
            console.log('sent!');
            if(response.data.success){
                console.log('sent!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

server side

```
app.post('/contact', function(req, res, next){
    var subject = req.query.nom;

    var nom = 'Nom complet: ' + req.query.nom + '<br/>';
    var organisation = 'Organisation: ' + req.query.organisation + '<br/>';
    var courriel = 'Courriel: ' + req.query.courriel + '<br/>';
    var telephone = 'Téléphone: ' + req.query.telephone + '<br/>';
    var body = 'Message: ' + req.query.message.replace('/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g', '<br/>'); // THE ERROR TRIGGERS HERE !!!
    var content = nom + organisation + courriel + telephone + body;
    console.log(subject);
    console.log(content);

    mailer.sendMail('aaa@gmail.com', subject, content, next);
});
```

mailer

```
var mailer = require('nodemailer');

var EMAIL_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'aaa@gmail.com';
var EMAIL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD = 'aaaa';

var smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: EMAIL_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        pass: EMAIL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD
    }
});

exports.sendMail = function(toAddress, subject, content, next){
    var success = true;
    var mailOptions = {
        to: toAddress,
        subject: subject,
        html: content
    };

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, res){
        if(error){
            console.log('[ERROR] Message NOT sent: ', error);
            success = false;
        } else {
            console.log('[INFO] Message sent: ' + res.message);
        }
        next(error, success);
    });
}
```

but, i'm getting an error on the node.js console on the marked line:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Any brilliant idea need I to do to fix that, please?

Comment: @mscdex, they may have the same title, but it's not the same purpose of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error message because req.query.message is undefined. Check that the variable req.query.message exists and this should work.

Comment: Okay, then how to get parameters from a post request ?

Comment: for POST request: req.body; for GET request: req.params